If $G_0$ is dense in $L^p([0,1])$, is $G_1 := \{ \int_0^x g(s) ds: g \in G_0 \}$ also?

Given a dense class $G_0 \subset L^p([0,1])$, $p \in [1,\infty]$, determine, depending on the value of $p$, whether $G_1 := \{ \int_0^x g(s) ds: g \in G_0  \}$ is necessarily also dense in $L^p([0,1])$?

This is a question from a qualifying exam that I am not sure how to answer.
One thing I'm semi-confident about is that $||f-g||_p < \epsilon$ does not imply any closeness in $L^p$ for $f$ and $\int_0^x g$, in general. One quick example is if $f = g = \chi_{[0,1]}$, in which case $\int_0^x g = x$.
However, I'm not sure how to think, in general, about the possibility that there might be another element $h \in G_1$ (unrelated to $g$ in $G_0$), such that $h \approx f$ in $L^p$.
As a sketch for the above case,  if $g_2 = a \chi_{(0,\epsilon)} + b\chi_{(\epsilon,1)}$, where $a $ is huge and $b \approx 0$, then $\int_0^x g = h(x)$ sharply rises to $1$ on $(0,\epsilon)$, and is approximately $1$ on the majority, $(\epsilon,1)$, so that this $h \approx f$ in $L^p$.

An idea for the $p=\infty$: any element of $G_1$ will need to be (absolutely) continuous. But continuous functions are not dense in $L^\infty$. For $p\neq \infty$, perhaps you can show that $G_1$ is dense in the set of continuous functions that are zero at $x=0$.

Surprisingly, the answer is positive for $1\leq p<\infty$. If $p=\infty$ the claim is false because the functions in $G_1$ must take $0$ at $0$, so they can never converge to the constant function $1$ (say). For $p<\infty$, I will need a few lemmas.
Lemma 1: If $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^p[0,1]$, then $g_n:=\int_0^x f_nd\mu\rightarrow g:=\int_0^x f d\mu$ in $L^p[0,1]$.
Proof: By Holder inequality, $|\int_0^x (f_n - f) d\mu| \leq \|f_n-f\|_p\cdot\|1_{[0,x]}\|_{q} \leq \|f_n-f\|_p$ where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Therefore,
$$\|g_n-g\|_p = \int_0^1 \left|\int_0^x (f_n-f)d\mu ^p\right|^{1/p} d\mu(x) \leq \int_0^1 \|f_n-f\|_p^{\frac{1}{p}}d\mu = \|f_n-f\|_p^{\frac{1}{p}}\rightarrow 0$$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.
Now, we will focus our analysis on continuously differentiable functions on $[0,1]$ (i.e. functions whose derivative is continuous). Since these contains the polynomial functions, by Stone-Weirstrass theorem the space of continuously differential functions is dense in $L^p([0,1])$. We have the following lemma.
Lemma 2: If $f$ is continuously differentiable and $f(0)=0$, then there exists a sequence $g_n\in G_1$ so that $g_n\rightarrow f$.
Proof: Since $f'$ is continuous, $f'\in L^p[0,1]$. Therefore there are $f_n\in G_0$ so that $f_n\rightarrow f'$ in $L^p$. By Lemma $1$, we see that $g_n:=\int_0^x f_n d\mu$ converges to $\int_0^x f'(t)dt = f(x)-f(0)=f(x)$.
To complete the proof it is left to show that continuously differentiable functions with $f(0)=0$ are dense. It is suffices to show that for every constant $C\not = 0$ there is a sequence of continuously differentiable functions with $f(0)=0$ converging to $C$. I only have a sketch proof here: For each $n$ choose $f_n$ that is $0$ on $[0,\frac{1}{n}]$ and then smoothly varies to $C$ on $[\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}]$ and then constant $C$ on $[\frac{2}{n},1]$. In $L^p$ such sequence of functions converge to $C$.

That’s very unexpected. Thank you! Can I ask how you went about thinking about it?

@algebroo I tried to check what happens when $G_0$ is the set of all polynomials. Then I realized G1 is the set of all polynomials with zero constant term. I assumed that you could use polynomials of higher degree to approximate constant polynomials, but I couldn't find a simple proof so I introduced those continuously differentiable functions.
